# DBLP-like resources for disciplines other than CS

Tags: publications, google-scholar

dblp.org is a free resource that lists papers from conferences and journals (including online venues like arxiv) in CS.

It also generates pages for the authors which have a publication in these venues and lists all the papers by that author.

It also makes its entire dataset available as free for download.

I'm wondering if similar resources exist for other disciplines. Search engines like Google Scholar are different because you have to already know what you're looking for before you find it.

In contrast, on DBLP you can start with a particular paper, then see all the other papers by the author, be able to browse venues which you may not have known about and see papers from those venues, and so on.

Comment: So you search data for which field other than CS in particular?  Or do you search data for a (still to be defined) field where CS could offer additional insight?

Comment: Search for data in other fields. Ideally a single site which lists publications from a lot of fields would be the best. I think I wouldn't want to specify particular ones (instead of asking "does DBLP for X exist?" for different fields X, this question is "if you know a field X where DBLP for X exists, please tell us about the field and the website")